# using nth to margin links

Tags: html, css

If I have 9 `li` and I need `2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9 to be margin-left: 20px;` how would I write this formula?

```
.mySheet li:nth-child(What Goes Here???) {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: How about using a class? Using index numbers seems like something that'd just be confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nth-child(N) where N is the order of the element

i.e.

```
<li>test</li>
<li>test2</li>
<li>test3</li>

<style>li:nth-child(2) { color: red; }</style>
```

In the above example the second li would have red text.

You can also specify increments, but it's slightly more complex than the above example... i.e. if I want every 3rd li to have a particular style:

```
<style>li:nth-child(3n+1) { color: red; }</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

i would do : `li:nth-child(3n-2)`  to include first `li` as well (not `margin-left`) any other will do the `margin-left` :).

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/hymGa/)

basicly :

```
li {
 margin-left:20px;
}
li:nth-child(3n-2) {
  margin:0;
}
```

---

if you like it better the other way :it would be :

```
li:nth-child(3n), li:nth-child(3n-1) {
 margin-left:20px;
}

li {
  margin:0;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/sfKtE/)**

---

So i would go for the first one , shorter.